# Disable Leap Motion from reading frames

Tags: javascript, selenium, leap-motion

I'm writing a web app that uses the Leap Motion as a controller through javascript.  My problem is that when I go to do selenium testing, even if the Leap device is disconnected, the controller keeps grabbing empty frames.  This makes it very difficult, if not impossible, to simulate leap pointables and gestures properly because half the time it's reading "no pointables here!"

I really don't want to add a "testing scenario" or "if(testing)" to the application - the point is to test the code that will run at release, not a special case.  If I could just disable the leap controller from selenium, feed in fake/generated frames, and then only run my own functions, that would be best.  I've been combing through the leap documentation, and I haven't found anything that legitimately stops the controller from reading frames.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure why you see this behavior. When I unplug my Leap Motion controller, the web socket server stops sending frames.

Comment: If that's true, then it really is strange.  It's possible that it's due to something else, but after narrowing it down quite a bit, that seems to be the behavior.  I guess I'll keep looking into it, under the assumption that I'm just wrong, and see if there are any other possibilities.

Comment: Are you using the latest LM software (1.0.8) and leap.js library?

Comment: LM is up to date, but it's possible leap.js isn't (I'll get on that).  However, since the behavior seems to have gotten up and left on its own now, I'd say this question is moot.  Probably just a bug of some kind.